# Can't NSLog my objects in an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an array(taskDays) which I have stored in to class
which contains an array(datedTask) and a
NSdate(deadline), in the class array I store another class(datedTask obj) which contains a
NSString(title) and a NSDate(duedate).
When I try to NSLog deadline from main it works but when I try to NSLog
title or duedate xcode crashes.
I have included a picture so you guys can check it out.
If you want I can upload my code somewhere because I really don't know
which code to include here.

Thanks in advance!

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TmZr.png)

Included the NSLog code since I think it might be the problem there:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [taskDay[0] title); //Makes stuff crash
NSLog(@"%@", [taskDay[0] datedTask); //How would I code to access the
                                     //title in dated task?
```

LIUTaskDay.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class LIUDatedTask;

@interface LIUTaskDay : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *datedTask;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *deadline;
- (void)addDatedTask:(LIUDatedTask *)d;



@end
```

LIUTaskDay.m

```
#import "LIUTaskDay.h"
#import "LIUDatedTask.h"

@interface LIUTaskDay ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_datedTask;
}

@end



@implementation LIUTaskDay

- (void)setDatedTask:(NSArray *)d {
    _datedTask = [d mutableCopy];
}

- (NSArray *)datedTask {
    return [_datedTask copy];
}

- (void)addDatedTask:(LIUDatedTask *)d {
    // Is datedTask nil?
    if (!_datedTask) {
        //Create the array
        _datedTask = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [_datedTask addObject:d];
    d.taskDay = self;

}

@end
```

LIUDatedTask.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LIUSimpleTask.h"
@class LIUTaskDay;

@interface LIUDatedTask : LIUSimpleTask

@property (nonatomic) NSDate *dueDate;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *completedDate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) LIUTaskDay *taskDay;


- (instancetype) initWithTitle:(NSString *)t
                 initWithDueDate:(NSDate *)dd;

@end
```

LIUDatedTask.m

```
#import "LIUDatedTask.h"
#import "LIUTaskDay.h"

@implementation LIUDatedTask

- (instancetype) initWithTitle:(NSString *)t
               initWithDueDate:(NSDate *)dd;
{

    if (self = [super initWithTitle:t]) {
        _dueDate = [dd copy];
    }

    return self;



}

- (void)taskCompleted
{
    [super taskCompleted];

    _completedDate = [NSDate date];

}


@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LIUDatedTask.h"
#import "LIUTaskDay.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSDateComponents *components;

        NSDate *date;

        NSCalendar *gregorian;

        NSMutableArray *taskDay = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bok1"];

        components = [NSDateComponents new];
        [components setYear:2016];
        [components setDay:21];
        [components setMonth:1];

        gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

        date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        LIUDatedTask *tmpLIUDatedTask = [[LIUDatedTask alloc]initWithTitle:string initWithDueDate:date];

        LIUTaskDay *tmpLIUTaskDay = [[LIUTaskDay alloc]init];

        [tmpLIUTaskDay addDatedTask:tmpLIUDatedTask];


        components = [NSDateComponents new];
        [components setYear:2017];
        [components setDay:2];
        [components setMonth:2];

        gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

        date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        tmpLIUTaskDay.deadline = date;

        [taskDay addObject:tmpLIUTaskDay];

        //NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", [day1[0] title],[day1[0] dueDate],[day1[0] deadline]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [taskDay[0] title]);



    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the crash log:

2016-01-10 13:26:41.749 chrjo564_Ny[1072:41244] -[LIUTaskDay   title]:   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100603220
2016-01-10 13:26:41.751 chrjo564_Ny[1072:41244] *** Terminating   app due  to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-  [LIUTaskDay title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100603220'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bd2003c  **exceptionPreprocess + 172

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8a2fe76e   objc_exception_throw + 43

    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bd230ad -  [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205

    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bc68e24   ___forwarding_** + 1028
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bc68998  _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   objclabb4-chrjo564_Ny               0x0000000100002090 main + 816
    6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8a4ee5c9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: The most significant information is `[LIUTaskDay title]: unrecognized selector sent`. That means somewhere the message `title` is sent to `LIUTaskDay` which doesn't respond to that message.What is `LIUTaskDay`?

Comment: LIUTaskDay is the class that contains an array and NSDate,  
In the array I will store the class which contains the title and due date.  
I have update with my NSLog which might be the problem.

Comment: The object at index 0 of the `taskDay` array obviously doesn't have a method or property `title`.

Comment: no the title lies in the datedTask which lies in the array in taskDay.  
But how do I access title in datedTask then?

Comment: Don't say no, the compiler isn't mistaken. Maybe it's` [[taskDay[0] datedTask] title]`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean no in that you were wrong, just no in that TaskDay  doesn't have the title.  
Tried what you wrote there but it gave warning before I could compile so.    
I have updated with more code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `taskDay` is an array for `LIUTaskDay` class.

Your `LIUDatedTask` is stored in the `_datedTask` array of `LIUTaskDay`.

To access `LIUDatedTask` object, you need to call `datedTask` method of `LIUTaskDay`.

---

So `taskDay[0]` is `tmpLIUTaskDay`.

`[taskDay[0] datedTask]` is the task array.

`[taskDay[0] datedTask][0]` is the `tmpLIUDatedTask`.

`NSLog(@"%@", [[taskDay[0] datedTask][0] title])` is what you want.

---

You may use generic type for the NSArray to help you. Something like `NSMutableArray<LIUDatedTask *>`.

And you may want to follow some naming convention.

Comment: Thank you for super fast feedback, this is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [taskDay[0][0] title]);
```

Comment: This still makes it crash, I'm trying to access title which lies inside datedTask which lies inside taskDay.